# Different behavior Chrome vs Edge

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, I have a small app, when I run it on chrome (F5 on visual) it opens `127.0.0.1/Index` and shows error: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

But when I run it on Edge it opens my page and all is good with the address `http://localhost:50060/`

that's not the first time that I have issues with chrome (the browser that I like)

why is that?

Comment: Try changing the port number in your project.

Comment: @Pr0misPAtel It works thanks